# How can I get a color from a hex string on web page? By selecting it, for example

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, color-picker

This is a web [page with documentation](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#color). It explains `color` option of charts.

[image]

I want to know the visual value of a hex string. How may I get it? ColorZilla is no good here with its eyedropper.

The best option would be to select it and select 'Show color' in chrome menu on mouse right button click.

OS is Ubuntu, unfortunately, options may be restricted, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an advanced way to make it without creating new tab

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Color Show",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content-script.js"],
    "matches": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.contextMenus.removeAll(() => { 
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: 'Show color',
        contexts: ['selection'],
        onclick: (e, tab) => {
            const selected = e.selectionText;
            const tabId = tab.id; 

            if(selected.match(/^#(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{3}){1,2}$/)) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
                    color: selected
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**content-script.js**

```js
// create simple modal in a shadow dom
const host = document.createElement('div'); 
const shadowRoot = host.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

// you can tune modal styles here
shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<div id="color_box" style="display:none; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index:9999; width: 80px; height: 80px"></div>';
document.body.appendChild(host);

const colorBox = shadowRoot.getElementById('color_box');

// show color by the message from background script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(request => {
    colorBox.style.backgroundColor = request.color;
    colorBox.style.display = 'block';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension that uses [chrome.contextMenus](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) to provide the functionality you mention. For example, the following extension will open a new tab filled with the color that matches the selected hex string when clicked on its context menu:

**background.js**

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Show color",
    contexts: ["selection"],
    onclick: function(details) {
        if (/(?:#[0-9a-fA-F]{3}|#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})$/.test(details.selectionText))
            chrome.tabs.create({url:'javascript:document.write("<title>' + details.selectionText + '</title><body style=background-color:' + details.selectionText + '></body>")'});
    }
});
```

You need to add "tabs" and "contextMenus" to the manifest permissions.